# Querying an external DB in PowerApps does not return data

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to encapsulate a query in a view to another SQL Server database (in the same server than the one I'm currently using) but it does not bring any rows or data in PowerApps.

The view works when SQL querying it, I have simplify it to be just a SELECT but still no results. The weird thing is that, when I check at the variable assigned to, PowerApps can determine what fields should be returned, but no rows.

What could be wrong? I thought that by encapsulating in a view, it should work no problem

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in the past and what we most often forget with the SQL Server connector is that it requires two additional columns to work: ROWVERSION and IDENTITY

Once you get these 2 right, it will not matter if you use views or query the table directly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#known-issues-and-limitations-with-triggers

Comment: do you mean, add these 2 columns in the view?

Comment: I'm not sure if they need to be part of the view, but they sure have to exist as specified by MS